# Making nth child a random variable in CSS

Tags: css

I want to assign a random value to n in the css.  Ideally without javascript (and there are suggestion on how to do this in various posts but I then don't know how to insert the javascript into the css as the nth child element only seems to accept 'odd', 'even' 'n' or a numerical value.

Code as it stands:

```
.gallery > .gallery__list > li:nth-child(4n) {
grid-column: span 3; /* Spans two columns */
grid-row: span 3; /* Spans two rows */
}
```

I simply want '4' to a random value between 1 and 5 so it could be 2n sometimes and 3n others.

Comment: CSS does not have any capacity to understand or implement "random". You have to explicitly declare anything you want ahead of time. You can either do that when you are writing the CSS, or when you are writing JS, which will run and result in a fixed number before the CSS is parsed and applied to the page. Or, if you are using some server-side language like PHP or C#, you could have a random-number function there, too, somewhere.

Comment: can you describe what are you trying to achieve? maybe there is another solution for what you want to do?

Comment: Hi, am trying to create a grid of dots which is randomly created (so sometimes every 4th & 8th dot is missing, sometimes eyery 2nd and 5th.). I think the key thing is that CSS doesn't allow random.  The below seems a good workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with CSS - it's a styling language, not a programming language and doesn't have the capacity to 'run' any code. However, it is *relatively* straightforward with JS. I originally misread the selector as just `4`, not `4n`, which makes things a little more involved:

```js
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery > .gallery_list > li');
const separator = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4);

listItems.forEach((item, i) => {
  if ((i + 1) % separator === 0) {
    item.classList.add('span-3');
  }
});
```

```css
.span-3 {
  grid-column: span 3;
  grid-row: span 3;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <ul class="gallery_list">
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
    <li>Item Four</li>
    <li>Item Five</li>
    <li>Item Six</li>
    <li>Item Seven</li>
    <li>Item Eight</li>
    <li>Item Nine</li>
    <li>Item Ten</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This code will:

1. Select all the `li` from the direct path in the same way you would with CSS.
2. Generate a random number between 1-5. `Math.random` returns a random float between 0 and less than 1 so must be adjusted.
3. Loop over the list of `li` elements.
4. If the index `i` (which starts from 0) plus 1, divided by the random number, leaves no remainder (which we get with the modulo operator `%`) then it should be styled.
5. Add a class which contains the relevant styles. I changed this from directly modifying inline style with `style.gridColumn` e.t.c. because this makes it reusable and easier to toggle.

Include the JS inside a `script` tag inside your HTML, or ideally in a separate file which you reference by the script tag's `src` attribute.